# jQuery AJAX form data serialize using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am stuck in my code, I need to send data from the form to the check.php page and then process it.

This is my code:

The AJAX part:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var form=$("#myForm");
$("#smt").click(function(){
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:form.attr("action"),
        data:form.serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);  
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

The form:

```
<form action="check.php" method="post" name="myForm" id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="user" id="user" />
<input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" />
<input type="button" name="smt" value="Submit" id="smt" />
</form>
<div id="err"></div>
```

the php part:

```
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];

if($user=="tony")
{
    echo "HI ".$user;   
}
else
{
    echo "I dont know you.";    
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem then?

Comment: when i an clicking the button, nothing happens...

Comment: comment the ajax call and add a simple alert message in that function and tell the result of it. If the form is generated by other code or dynamically added use .on() or .live() depending on the jquery version.

Comment: use chrome's inspect elements after clicking the button. is it show some javascript errors?

Comment: Your code is correct.It goes to check.php page and displas message in console. If you want replace console.log(response); with alert(response).

Comment: thanx alot for your response, well with alert its working perfectly, its showing hi Tony when input is tony else "i dont know you", but they are showing in alert, i want them to show in the "err" div, with this code "success: function(response){
    $("#err").load("check.php"); 
   }" but when i am using it all the time it show the output of the else case, plese tell me where am i wrong.

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var form=$("#myForm");
    $("#smt").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:form.attr("action"),
            data:$("#myForm input").serialize(),//only input
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);  
            }
        });
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 8):

try it , but first be sure what is you response console.log(response) on ajax success from server

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var form=$("#myForm");
$("#smt").click(function(){
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:form.attr("action"),
        data:form.serialize(),

        success: function(response){
        if(response === 1){
            //load chech.php file  
        }  else {
            //show error
        }
        }
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same problem:
You have to unserialize the data on the php side.

Add to the beginning of your php file (Attention this short version would replace all other post variables):

```
parse_str($_POST["data"], $_POST);
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var form=$("#myForm");
    $("#smt").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:form.attr("action"),
            data:form.serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);  
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This is perfect code , there is no problem.. You have to check that in php script.

Comment: What else is needed in order to stay on the same page after the form is submitted?

Comment: prevent reload of page on submit if form is used

Comment: How do we get certain data from the response, like `article_id` given that `console.log(data)` is `article_id=300&parent_id=445&msg=Test`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this its working..

    <script>
      $(function () {
          $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'post',
                  url: '<?php echo base_url();?>student_ajax/insert',
                  data: $('form').serialize(),
                  success: function (response) {
                      alert('form was submitted');
                  }
                  error:function() {
                      alert('fail');
                  }
              });
          });
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follows -

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var form=$("#myForm");
$("#smt").click(function(){
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:form.attr("action"),
        data:form.serialize(),

        success: function(response){
        if(response == 1){
              $("#err").html("Hi Tony");//updated
        }  else {
            $("#err").html("I dont know you.");//updated
        }
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

PHP -

```
<?php
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];

if($user=="tony")
{
    echo 1;   
}
else
{
    echo 0;    
}
?>
```

Comment: yeah its working this way but for a second thoughts lets say we dont want to alert it, we want to show the result in the div "err", with this code "success: function(response){
    $("#err").load("check.php"); 
   }" but when doing this all the time its going into the else case and shows "i dont know you", what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" name="myForm" id="myForm">
```

replace with above form tag **remove action from form tag. and set url : "check.php" in ajax**
in your case first it goes to jQuery ajax then submit again the form. that's why it's creating issue.

i know i'm too late for this reply but i think it would help.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is in your php file. When you use jquery `serialize()` method you are sending a string, so you can not treat it like an array. Make a `var_dump($_post)` and you will see what I am talking about.

Comment: Do you have a solution ? Otherwise this should be a comment.